# The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We are joining 3 tables with ~21000 rows, ~2000 rows and ~1600 rows.

MAX_JOIN_SIZE is at ~8.000.000.
Each table contains a column named providerID.

The query is like:

```
SELECT
   A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM       A 
INNER JOIN B 
   ON A.ID = B.aID 
INNER JOIN C 
   ON A.ID = C.aID
WHERE
   A.providerID = 200 AND
   B.providerID = 200 AND
   C.providerID = 200
```

The whole query returns 3 rows and each where-line returns ~90, ~60, ~10 rows.

Setting BIG_SQL_QUERY isn't good enough as this problem suddenly occurred.

In my opinion the query optimizer should could handle the problem in first selecting from the 3 tables and then joining

Comment: What happens? Any indexes/keys?

Comment: please ask a question. Post current query plan as well.

Comment: what is the JOIN condition? Include providerID? is `<value>` the same for 3 providerID?

Comment: Pimary key but no indexes, is creating one the answer. Its an production database, any danger when creating an index?  How do I get the query plan? providerID is the same for each table its an integer.

Comment: only danger is will take some space but will be minimal, and you should always create index.  So you should learn about it https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: With so small number of records it should be no problem with adding indexes. Also please post full join conditions. Second thig is that if all <value> is equal you could join all tables on `providerID` and add only one condition in `where` clause

Comment: Mhh I still want to know why the db does not optimize the query like learned in university, but indexing seems to work for now.

Comment: Add `INDEX(providerID)` to each table.

Comment: Is there some reason for setting `max_join_size` so low?  ("No one" else does.)

Comment: @Rick James we a using a managed server and cannot change that value.

Comment: @dark_982 - Sounds like a dubious attempt at keeping you from writing a query that gets out of hand.

Comment: Yep I think so to. Anther thing I wasnt aware is that it seems like the dbms assumes the join size instead of doing query optimisation select from the tabels as far as possible and then doing joins (and before joining doing some assumtion about join size based on the result of the selection) I hope you get what Im trying to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
    FROM  A
    INNER JOIN  B  ON A.ID = B.aID
                  AND A.providerID = B.providerID
    INNER JOIN  C  ON A.ID = C.aID
                  AND A.providerID = C.providerID
    WHERE  A.providerID = 200
```

*and* add

```
A:  INDEX(providerID, ID)   -- In this order
B:  INDEX(providerID, aID)  -- In either order
C:  INDEX(providerID, aID)  -- In either order
```

If possible, please use the real names for tables and columns; sometimes there are useful clues of the *intent* which can help in dealing with performance (etc) issues.  If they weren't all "200", then my answer needs to have volcanic ash spewed onto it.

*Probably* the 'join' limit can be avoided by having these indexes.

It seems that `B` and `C` are strongly related; is there a reason to have two separate tables?  (Again, actual names might have answered this question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the filter to the JOIN condition

```
SELECT
   A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM   A 
JOIN   B 
  ON  A.<something> = B.<something>
 AND  A.providerID = <value>
 AND  B.providerID = <value>
JOIN   C
  ON  A.<something> = C.<something>
 AND  C.providerID = <value>
```

Now if providerID is the JOIN condition you get:

```
SELECT
   A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM   A 
JOIN   B 
  ON  A.providerID  = B.providerID 
 AND  A.providerID = <value>
JOIN   C
  ON  B.providerID  = C.providerID
```

Comment: Seems not to work. I added the join condition to my post.

Comment: Any decent query optimiser should not exhibit any difference regarding whether filters are in the `where` or the `join`, and users should not have to break the semantics of their code by moving things between.

Comment: `ON` should specify how the tables relate (`a.pid=b.pid`); `WHERE` should specify the filtering (`pid=200`).

Comment: @RickJames Can you elaborate on that? Is that a suggestion, best practice or there is another reason behind that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The OP wrote the query the 'correct' way.  It is "best practice" because it is clearer to the reader.  If it had been `LEFT JOIN`, then the result set is likely to be different -- a strong reason for distinguishing 'relation' versus 'filtering'.